# can't seem to register jquery in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am jsut recently learning to develop wordpress themes and at first I added the jquery script and other scripts like this:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But today while doing some tutorials I found that this is not the best way of doing things , so I started searching on the internet and I found how to do it:

```
  function register_js(){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery' , '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js');
   }
add_action('init' , 'register_js');
```

But for some reasons all the scripts I have on my page say that jQuery is not defined or $ is not defined.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the wp_enqueue_script function.

Detailed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_scrip

**Wordpress Example:**

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```